# Stripped commits on GIT repository with Bitbucket

Tags: git, logging, bitbucket

I removed the last 3 commits from my remote GIT repository (because I goofed!). This has worked fine and I have pushed the correct commits this time around and the repository is almost as it should be.

Bitbucket is still showing the original 3 commit messages in its "Overview" log and it also shows "stripped {commit-id}" for each of them. Is there a way to remove these messages from the log to tidy up the overview page?

**Added:** The commit log appears to be correct when viewed using the "Commits" tab and likewise when viewed using SourceTree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a feature of the overview tab of a Bitbucket repo, which reflects the [reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).
I don't see in the [Bitbucket documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Bitbucket+Documentation+Home;jsessionid=D76F7932B95A2BAB1BA5C7E7A5811780) any way to remove those "`stripped {commit-id}`", but if that does reflect the reflog, those elements will disappear after (by default) 90 days.

> Entries older than this time are pruned.
>   Without the option it is taken from configuration `gc.reflogExpire`, which in turn defaults to `90 days`.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed appear to be the case. I wasn't even aware of `git reflog`. So I have removed the offending record from my local repository using `git reflog delete HEAD@{3}` and this has worked locally. How can I push this to the origin repository?